# HazelCast Upgrade Issue from 2.5 to 3.8

Tags: guava, guice, hazelcast

I am upgrading HazelCast from 2.5 to 3.8 , but after upgrading I am getting below exception :

```
    com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive load of: .
.
.
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2201)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3934)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3938)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4821)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4827)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:48)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:50)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:136)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:547)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:884)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.<init>(SingleFieldInjector.java:42)
        at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.getInjectors(MembersInjectorStore.java:131)
        at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.createWithListeners(MembersInjectorStore.java:98)
```

Does any one has any idea ?

Comment: Can you post code of how you define cache, use and load a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bug in guice, when guice couldn't initialize inject a class due missing interface implementation binding or it fails during constructor initialization, it displays this error instead of actual error,
You can check, 
https://github.com/google/guice/issues/785

Below program fails with same error

```
`package com.guicetest;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Provider;
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Provides;
/* Dependencies:
Class01
  Class04
  Class03
Class02
  @Provides Class01
Class03
  Class01
Class04
  Class05
  Class01
Class05
  Interface01
 */
public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
            }
            @Provides
            public Class02 providesClass02(Provider<Class01> arg) {
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
class Class01 {
    @Inject
    public Class01(Provider<Class04> arg1, Provider<Class03> arg2) {
    }
}
class Class02 {
}
class Class03 {
    @Inject
    public Class03(Provider<Class01> arg) {
    }
}
class Class04 {
    @Inject
    public Class04(Provider<Class05> arg1, Provider<Class01> arg2) {
    }
}
class Class05 {
    @Inject
    public Class05(Provider<Interface01> arg) {
    }
}
interface Interface01 {
}`
```

You can find actual error by putting debug point on LocalCache in the exception cause and expand loader object, you will be able to find actual error,
[Finding actual error in intellij IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyQGg.png)